# How to index multiple a variable(x) for all levels of variables(y) at the same time?

Tags: r, variables, indexing

I will further explain with a simple example
If I had a dataset as follows:

```
Team   Score
Blue       4
Blue       8
Green      8
Orange     7
Blue       4
Red        5
Red        4
Orange     10
Blue       3
Green      8
Green      5
```

I want do to something to get the means that expresses:

```
mean(Score[Team=Blue])
mean(Score[Team=Green])...
```

I want to be able to do it all at once.

Comment: Please provide us a code-snippet of what you have tried so far

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for the link to the answer.
As far as what I've gotten to work is this:
team_Names<-levels(team)
i=0
while (i<5){
  i=i+1
  mean(Stock.p[Team==team_Names[i]])->tnames
  print(tnames)
  }

it works, but I don't know how to save the iterations as a vector

@Nevermore